# Does mistaken mean mis-taken as misunderstood means mis-understood?

Tags: meaning

Misunderstood pretty much means understood incorrectly-- by the same logic, would mistaken mean taken incorrectly?

Comment: Language isn't always logical. Have you checked a dictionary for the definition? Or are you asking about the [etymology of the word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mistaken&allowed_in_frame=0)?

Comment: Yes it would—if you understand "taken" to mean "apprehended or understood [to be true]," which is essentially Merriam-Webster's definition 14(a) of the transitive verb _take_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, this conclusion can't be reached. From Merriam-Webster's [closest definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistaken):

> Mistake (*verb*)
>   2. a : to misunderstand the meaning or intention of

This says nothing about how to break the *mis*- prefix out for analysis, but luckily, *mistaken*'s [etymology entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mistake) provides a useful origin:

> from a Scandinavian source such as Old Norse *mistaka* "take in error, miscarry"

Now we can safely say that the *mis*- prefix loosely means "__ *in error*." So, realizing that *misunderstood* can be turned into *understood in error*, the same rule can be applied to *mistaken*: **taken in error**.